# What is Angle(A,b) about something.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was reading a paper and came through a notation saying ....
Angle  = Angle(A,B) about C.

Can anybody tell me what exactly it means.
Thnaks,
Harsha

Answer (score 1):

It means $\angle ACB$. (Or Angle ACB)

[image]

$X$ denotes $\angle ACB$ here.